# MVC Jquery datatable not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

I downloaded my datatable [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.datatables) and installed it using nuget. Now I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvUbleb5YX8&list=PLM5JAv_WpgH-2RybAr_oss-V3O9JlLAkf) tutorial for the implementation of my datatable.

I tried adding it at my bundles, drag and drop, manual insert in my view but still not working.

TABLE

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="asd">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Remarks")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Payer Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Payer Address")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Motor No")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Chassis No")
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.remarks)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.payername)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.payeraddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.motor_no)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.chassis_no)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

SCRIPT

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#asd").DataTable();
        })

    </script>
}
```

LAYOUT PAGE

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you include `jquery{-version}.js`? (and look at the error messages in your browser console!)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is included in my Bundles Config

Comment: There are no bundles for `jquery` in the code you have shown! Again - look at the error messages in your console

Comment: @StephenMuecke The error showing is jquery is not defined and Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

Comment: Exactly :) - you have not loaded jquery (or you loaded it on the wrong order - it needs to be first)

Comment: @StephenMuecke How was it not loaded? Im kinda confused sr. In my _Layout.cshtml, in the body tag, @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") was included there. So should I declare the jquery again in the title?

Comment: Check the view source of the page and see the order of scripts being loaded to the page

Comment: No - you only load jquery once - but it needs to be before your `<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>` (but that script should be in the view, not the layout anyway unless you need it on every page - i.e. in the `@section scripts { ... }`)

Comment: Simply putting `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` before `jquery.dataTables.js` definition in layout page and your `DataTable` will work fine (assumed all view pages are required jQuery scripts).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Did that already as suggested by Stephen Muecke, the error that shows now is this, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

Comment: You can look at [this article](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function). Possibly you're loading multiple versions of jQuery or `datatable` script is missing/not loaded.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Ok. I figured it out, the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") was declared twice giving me this error. Thanks for the help